# TypeScript and rxjs. How can I access to an object and iterate it to show a table

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I can't access to `lstTest`, it appears as undefined in `console.log(response_testQ.lstTest);`, but is weird because when I put `console.log(response_testQ);`, `lstTest` appears as `Array(3)`.

[image: Console]

**How can I iterate inside lstTest with forEach(...)?**

```
export class testQ {
    lstTest?: Test[];
}

export class Test {
     TestId?: number;
}
```

*This a function that I execute*

```
    Test.SelectAllPaged(request_testQ).subscribe(
    {
        next: newrow => {
            const response_testQ = newrow.response as testQ;
            var TableContent: string = "";

            console.log(response_testQ);
            console.log(response_testQ.lstTest);

            response_testQ?.lstTest?.forEach(d => { //HERE IT DOESN'T ENTER
                TableContent += `<tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="custom-control">
                            <input id="Test${d.TestId}" type="checkbox">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;
            })
            },
            complete: () => {
                $(window).on("scroll", ScrollDownNSearch);
                console.log("Search finished");
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log("Error during server call. No internet connection?", err)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem is that response_testQ was giving me lstTestModel instead of lstTest